# JSF CommandButton action not invoked

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

I'm having a problem with JSF CommandButton action not being invoked.
I have a managed bean roleController, as in

```
@ManagedBean(name = "roleController")
@RequestScoped
public class RoleController {
        public Role getSelectedRole() {
    return selectedRole;
}

public void updateSelectedRole() {
    System.out.println(selectedRole.getRole());
}
```

In my .jsf file I'm trying to edit invoke updateSelectedRole action on h:commandButton, but it doesn't seem to work. I've tried to change the method name to incorrect one, and there's no exception thrown - but when I do the same with other form, the exception is thrown - so most likely the action isn't even invoked.

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="${param.action == 'edit'}">
    <h:form>
        <ol>
            <li>
                <label for="ID">
                    <h:outputText value="#{msg.roleEditID}" />
                </label>
                <h:inputText readonly="true" 
                    value="#{roleController.selectedRole.id}" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="Role">
                    <h:outputText value="#{msg.roleEditRole}" />
                </label>
                <h:inputText value="#{roleController.selectedRole.role}" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <h:commandButton value="#{msg.buttonUpdate}" 
                    action="#{roleController.updateSelectedRole()}"/>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </h:form>
</h:panelGroup>
```

I found that it may be caused be nested forms, but that's not the case in this example. Is it possible that the root of this problem is my navigation rule?

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/admin/roles.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <to-view-id>/admin/roles.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <from-outcome>true</from-outcome>
        <redirect>
            <view-param>
                <name>action</name>
                <value>edit</value>
            </view-param>
        </redirect>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Answer (score 30):

The action is not been invoked, because the command button component is not rendered.

During processing of the form submit, the `rendered="${param.action == 'edit'}"` on the parent panel group component is been re-evaluated (as safeguard against tampered/hacked requests). However, as you're apparently not retaining that request parameter in the postback (at least, nothing in the code proves otherwise), it evaluates to `false`. And thus the parent panel group component is not rendered, including all of its childen.

You need to make sure that the `rendered` attribute of the command button and all of its parent components evaluates to `true` during the form submit. In this particular case you can achieve that by retaining the request parameter by including a `<f:param>` in the command button itself.

```html
<h:commandButton ...>
    <f:param name="action" value="#{param.action}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

#### See also:

- [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked/2120183#2120183) - Point 5 applies to you

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, it's recommend to ban the usage of `${}` in JSF as it would otherwise lead to unnecessary confusion and questions. Just stick to `#{}` all the time.

Answer (score 0):

```
<h:commandButton value="#{msg.buttonUpdate}" 
  action="#{roleController.updateSelectedRole()}"/>
```

change it to

```
 <h:commandButton value="#{msg.buttonUpdate}" 
  action="#{roleController.updateSelectedRole}"/>
```

You don't need the brackets for your action call.

```
public void updateSelectedRole() {
System.out.println(selectedRole.getRole());
}
```

and the method action method needs to return a string

```
public String updateSelectedRole() {

    System.out.println(selectedRole.getRole());
    return "true";
}
```

Comment: I've already tried that, didn't help.

Comment: @DanielCisek saw a second problem as well. Updated the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work.

Comment: Brackets are supported since EL 2.2. If OP had used EL 2.1 or older, he would have gotten an `ELException` on that. So that definitely isn't the problem. Returning string is not a requirement. Void is also perfectly fine. If it was really invalid, it would have thrown an `ELException` as well. This is however not the case.

Answer (score 0):

the request from the client must be encapsulated within an HTTP form

Answer (score -2):

this order change worked in my case:

```
<h:form>
  <h:panelGroup rendered="${param.action == 'edit'}">
  .
  .
  .
  </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Sure you did not change anything else? Or that this change triggered a deployment correcting some other error?